# Regex: Parsing a string containing last, first and middle initial

Tags: java, regex

I can have either string in the following format:

```
Doe, John F -
Doe, John -
```

I have written the following which works in these two cases:

```
"^(.+),\\s(.+)\\s([A-Za-z])?\\s?-$"

"Doe, John F-" (no space after “Middle_Init”)
"Doe, John -"  (no middle initial)
```

But it doesn’t work with

```
"Doe, John F -" (space after the middle initial and the hyphen)
```

I’m not sure how to make the space optional. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run into a person, like myself, who has a middle name and a first initial?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to catch separate groups for all 3 components, this regexp should work:
`"^(.+),\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)?\\s*-$"` (formatted as Java String)

[Regexp demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydn2jwar)

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted but am new so you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both cases:

`^(.+),\s(.+)\s?-$`